# React-Redux child props not updating with parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Redux store changes are reflected in my parent/wrapper class, but the prop passed to the child is not updated.

I've tried mutating the store differently to try and coax redux updates but realized this isn't the issue because my parent component is getting the updated information just fine. I've also tried storing the data in the parent's state as I've read but I've had issues with the asynchronous hook calls.

Parent

```
const ReportWrapper = ({ report: { loading, report, error }, match, getReport, editReport, finalizeReport }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getReport(match.params.id);
  }, [getReport, match.params.id]);

  const [displayFollowup, toggleDisplayFollowup] = useState(false);

  // deal with invalid urls/report not found
  if (error && error.status === 404) return <Redirect to="/reports/404" />;
  // loading case
  if (loading || report === null) return <Spinner />;

  const meta = Object.assign({}, report.meta);
  const initialReport = Object.assign({}, report.initialReport);
  const followup = Object.assign({}, report.followup);

  const initialValues = {
    id: report._id,
    meta,
    initialReport,
    followup
  };
  // after adding a followup, it is properly presented in the initialvalues and followup variables here and matches the redux store
  return (
    <Report
      initialValues={initialValues}
      editreport={editReport}
      displayfollowup={displayFollowup}
      toggledisplayfollowup={toggleDisplayFollowup}
      finalizereport={finalizeReport}
    />
  );
};
```

Child

```
const Report = ({ initialValues, editreport, finalizereport, history, displayfollowup, toggledisplayfollowup }) => {

.....
console.log(initialValues); <--- Doesn't reflect the new redux store state
.....
}
```

All code for Report.js: https://gist.github.com/arranw/2bd90c4dd07ab65d1c914e2320791c58

I would like both components to reflect the updated store state, but the value only makes it to the parent and the child doesn't receive the new values through the prop.

Comment: Can you put here your all code of "Report" component?

Comment: Here it is: https://gist.github.com/arranw/2bd90c4dd07ab65d1c914e2320791c58

Comment: I think it would be working, if you change this component to "PureComponent"

Comment: Is there a way to use that in a functional component or do I have to use a class?

Comment: @arran, with so much code, is challenging to help you. You should try to create a minimal, reproducible example that shows your current problem. Check the ["How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) section at the Help Center to learn how to create one. Then share it using [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io) or a similar tool.

Comment: I think you should use class component. You can't make PureComponent as function.

Comment: OP you mention using React Redux, but I don't even see any Redux (let alone React-Redux) code anywhere, not in your post and not in your gist.  That means that *from what we can see* only React is in play here, and React re-renders your component, and potentially its children, when props change.  In other words, your code should be working, but the problem may well be in the missing React-Redux piece.  Show me the `connect`! :)

Comment: @guzmonne alright, I'll try. I wasn't sure if that would be feasible with all the different files involved with redux and such but that'll be the next thing I do

Comment: @iskaandar class components are backwards: they're the old/wrong way to do React.  Functions are React's future (remember, React *started* 100% class-based: I really don't think Facebook invested millions to introduce hooks, and all the other changes which made class-less components possible, because they *liked* using classes).  And furthermore, PureComponent is not some magic fix all.  It just changes the default implementation of shouldComponentUpdate to do a shallow comparison.

Answer (score 0):

So this wasn't actually a react or redux issue, but an issue with Formik.

Solution:
enableReinitialize prop on my Formik component allowed the form state to update with it's props. Thanks everyone for your help.